# How to import custom function inside allmodules?

Tags: typescript, webpack

I have function:

```
function __extends(d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
}
```

How i can pass with Webpack that function as variable `__extends` inside ALL modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make a function available in all modules is moving this function into a module and let webpack automatically load it when required. To do this you just need to:

1.- Move your `__extends` function into a module that exports this function:

**extends.js**

```
function __extends(d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
}

module.exports = __extends;
```

2.- Configure webpack to automatically require/import this module whenever `__extends` is used as a free variable. For this just use the [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#provideplugin):

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  // Your other configuration
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      __extends: './extends'
    })
  ]
};
```

Now you are free to use `__extends` anywhere without having to explicitly import/require it. Webpack will take care for you.

Comment: I did that, but got error: `Cannot find module "./extends"`

`extends.js` is near webpack config (for testing)

Comment: After setting `modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', '.']` everybody works fine.

Comment: It is weird. It shouldn't complain because you actually have the `extends.js` module right next to the `webpack.config.js`.

Answer (score 1):

Is your custom function somewhere in the global scope? You can use the [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin) to alias it:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
__extends: "window.__extends"
})
```

Comment: any way to do that without passing __exteds as global variable?
and if so, any way to do that without DefinePlugins? I use gulp-webpack and plugins not supported inside gulp-webpack config

Comment: The only other way around I can think of is to bundle your __extends function definition together with your app, and let webpack wire it up automatically with the rest of your code.

Comment: if i bundle this function with my app - i need to import (or require) that function inside modules? if so - this is a bad solution =(

Answer (score 0):

Now `__extends` as node module!

https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-extends

```
// webpack configuration object

plugins: [
    new ProvidePlugin({
        __extends: 'typescript-extends'
    })
],
```